# Trouble understanding file partitions

Tags: linux, centos, partition, memory, fdisk

I am trying to run fdisk on /dev/sda and create a new partition on /dev/sda3. I am not understanding what to do if no free sectors are available. I looked online and found different solutions and I am not sure which of them to follow. One solution suggested to delete the /dev/sda partition and repartition it.

I am new to linux and do not fully understand the implications of this.

1. How can I check what files are on /dev/sda?
2. What is the difference between primary and extended partions?
3. How can I tell if deleting /dev/sda partion will break anything relating to this VMs operating system?(This is a freshly built VM).
4. How should I approach this problem

Please let me know if there is any other information I can give you. I have researched as much as I can on my own but I weary about proceeding because I do not want to break anything.

```
[root@itdmci dev]# pvs
  PV         VG     Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
  /dev/sda2  centos lvm2 a--  <7.00g    0
[root@itdmci dev]# vgs
  VG     #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  centos   1   2   0 wz--n- <7.00g    0
[root@itdmci dev]# lvs
  LV   VG     Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root centos -wi-ao----  <6.20g
  swap centos -wi-ao---- 820.00m
[root@itdmci dev]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000e67f7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2099199     1048576   83  Linux
/dev/sda2         2099200    16777215     7339008   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 17.2 GB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xe165f99a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    33552383    16775168    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 859 MB, 859832320 bytes, 1679360 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 6652 MB, 6652166144 bytes, 12992512 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

[root@itdmci dev]# sudo fdisk /dev/sda

The device presents a logical sector size that is smaller than
the physical sector size. Aligning to a physical sector (or optimal
I/O) size boundary is recommended, or performance may be impacted.
Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): n
Partition type:
   p   primary (2 primary, 0 extended, 2 free)
   e   extended
Select (default p): p
Partition number (3,4, default 3): 3
No free sectors available
```

Here are the steps I would follow after I can make a new partition on /dev/sda3

1. partition to LVM using: pvcreate
2. vgextend
3. lvresize

I am including the future steps for context on what my ultimate goal is, but I am moreso just making this post for clarification on the questions I posted up top.

Comment: LVM is likely adding to your confusion. LVM is an abstraction layer between the physical disk and the filesystem. Section 11 here should help https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/ch-lvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll clear up the terminology first before going into the details. `/dev/sda` is a hard disk attached to your VM. The naming convention is that sda is the first disk, sdb would be the second disk and so on.

Let's say that you have a 1 TiB disk attached in this manner. You would want to use it for different purposes - OS, media, games, software and so on. To streamline such a layout, you can divide the disk into continuous sections. These divisions are called partitions.

Partitions are represented on the disk using a concept called a partition table. Partition tables are of two types: MBR, a legacy type, and GPT, a more modern variant. The MBR type had a limitation that you could only have four partitions. These are called primary partitions. However, real-world requirements demanded more than four partitions, so the standard included the concept of extended partitions. These are essentially sub-partitions inside a primary partition. Having extended partitions pushes the limit of possible to a higher number. The GPT standard treats all partitions as primary, but you can have up to 128 of them.

So if a disk /dev/sda is divided into three partitions, they would be /dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, /dev/sda3.

Once you have a partition, you need to add a filesystem on top of it before it can be used by the OS. You can put a filesystem directly on a partition such as /dev/sda2, but the filesystem is then stricly bound by the size of the partition. Resizing such a filesystem can be a difficult and sometimes impossible exercise.

This is where LVM comes in. LVM adds an abstraction layer between partitions and filesystems. The idea is that you add partitions or even entire disks to a pool called a volume group. From the volume group, you're free to size the partitions in any way you see fit. Naturally, this adds a bit of complexity to the stack, but the flexibility it brings in is usually worth it.

---

On to the numbers. In your `fdisk -l` output, you can see this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
```

So your disk is about 8.5 GiB in size, and has 16777216 sectors (an old unit for sizing disks).

`Disk label type: dos` identifies that you have an MBR disk.

Your partition table comes after this. `/dev/sda1` runs from sector 2048 to 2099199, and `/dev/sda2` runs from 2099200 to 16777215 - the last sector of the disk. There's really no room for expansion here. If you remove either of these partitions, you'll break your OS. `/dev/sda1` is your boot partition, so if you remove that, you'll no longer be able to boot your VM.

You do have a `/dev/sdb` device listed with size 17.2 GiB. Based on the filesystem, I think that it's some sort of USB device.

In your current situation, you have two options to add a new partition:

1. Leverage the fact that you're on a VM. Increase the size of the VM disk from the hypervisor, and then resize it on the guest. Then use fdisk to create a new physical partition.
2. Leverage LVM. Add a new disk to your VM, then add it to the `centos` volume group. From there, add a new logical partition.

Both of these options should provide a similar end result.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This has cleared up a lot of my questions. Trying this now